# How can I avoid space while using pseudo-elements in multi-line markup?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, pseudo-element, spaces

I raised a qustion here: [How to avoid spaces when wrapping markup across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950882/html-avoid-spaces-when-write-codes-in-multiple-lines), and learned that I can avoid white space while writing markup across **multiple lines**. However, when I apply this method to a element with pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`, it doesn't work.

Similarly, if I write markup on only one line as `<span class="inline">i, friend</span>`, it will display **"Hi, friends"** as I wish.
But when I divide it into multiple lines, it will display **"H i, friend s"** with needless **white spaces** within it.

Here is my css code & html code::

```css
.parent {
  font-size: 0;
}
.parent > span {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.parent > span::before {
  content: "H";
}
.parent > span::after {
  content: "s";
}
```

```html
<p class="parent">
  <span>
    i, friend
  </span>
</p>
```

**I know it's not recommended** to write

```
<span>
  i, friend
</span>
```

instead of `<span>i, friend</span>`.

But if I insist on it(forgive me), is it possible to display **"Hi, friends"** as I wish?

Comment: The only way I can see this working is to float everything left and put the before and after on the parent: https://jsfiddle.net/n8hxtzos/.  Seems like you are creating extra work for yourself, but if you are going to be stubborn...

Comment: You may use a negative `margin-right` (and `margin-left` for the `::after`) to align the letters. Hackish as hell, and you'll still have a white space (in front of the whole text instead of inside) but might look like what you want (except if 1st or last letter is on their own text line).

Comment: @Pete Thanks. Your code really works. Could you tell me why float can trim needless spaces?

Comment: @Pete seems a small problem here. If I add more `<span>` within `<p>`, it can only add "H" for the 1st `<span>` and "s" for the last one. Anyway, it works right when I have only one child element.

Comment: @Xenos Thanks for your advice. I'm trying to seek for more possibilities, so that's why I look a little stubborn :)

Comment: Thanks to @Nenad Vracar , @Syntac and others' work, and I realized that **parent class is not required here**. But I won't remove them 'cause it may make their answers look wrong. So I put it here. Here is my codes for 2 or more `span`: [css solution from @Nenad Vracar](https://jsfiddle.net/lovemind/cjky58qp/) & [js solution from @Syntac](https://jsfiddle.net/lovemind/ax8pxnqc/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `inline-flex` instead of `inline-block`

```css
.parent {
  font-size: 0;
}
.parent > span {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.parent > span::before {
  content: "H";
}
.parent > span::after {
  content: "s";
}
```

```html
<p class="parent">
  <span>
    i, friend
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Amazing! It works. Could you please tell me why `flex` can avoid space here?

Comment: Problem with your code was white space in html and flexbox removes them.

Comment: Is `font-size:0` required? That discards relative font units.

Comment: Well it removes white-space from parent but not from span https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1265/

Comment: @Xenos Yes.It's not required. I used it to avoid space between two inline-block elements.It's not needed here. Thanks for Nenad Vracar's codes.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know a CSS based solution, but you can remove the text nodes (which cause the spaces) with some simple JS:

```
var pElement = document.querySelector(".parent>span");
for (node of pElement.childNodes)
    if (node.nodeType === 3 )
        node.textContent = node.textContent.trim();
```

inside `window.onload` or `<body onload=" ... "`

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I tried your script, but it doesn't seem to work for me .

Comment: @LoveMind Sorry, that's weird :/. I copied all your code to a jsFiddle and it worked for me (and logically this apporoach will always work).

Comment: Oh, it's my fault. I should say sorry. After read the frame code in jsFiddle, I find that I used `window.onload` in a wrong way. btw, I modified your code with `querySelectorAll` so that I can apply it to cases with 2 or more `span`. Much thanks to you!